# Locate doesn't work with LOCATE_PATH environment variable

Tags: linux

I'm setting the LOCATE_PATH environment variable and using it as follows:

```
$ export LOCATE_PATH='/usr/filesystem/'
$ locate -d mydatabase1.db:mydatabase2.db search_string
```

I get the following error message:

```
   locate: can not stat () 'mydatabase1.db': No such file or directory
   locate: can not stat () 'mydatabase2.db': No such file or directory
   locate: I/O error reading '/mnt/scratch/database': Is a directory
```

How am I supposed to properly use the LOCATE_PATH environment variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

If your database files are in `/usr/filesystem`, then use

```
$ export LOCATE_PATH=/usr/filesystem/mydatabase1.db:/usr/filesystem/mydatabase2.db
$ locate search_string
```

Or use the `-d` option (if `LOCATE_PATH` is not set or different)

```
$ locate -d /usr/filesystem/mydatabase1.db:/usr/filesystem/mydatabase2.db search_string
```

Comment: @macdays Good! If this solves your issue, please consider ["accepting" the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). This is the best way to show gratitude on this site.  Accepting an answer not only marks the question as resolved, but also signals to _future readers_ that the accepted answer actually solved the issue.  More information about this is available here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers